# Open map in Banach algebra

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I'm having trouble showing a certian function is open and can be extended.

Let $\Omega$ be a *completely regular* topological space and $A=C_b(\Omega)$ the space of all complex-values bounded continuous functions on $\Omega$. For every $\lambda \in \Omega$, the consider the functional $\phi_{\lambda}:$ $A\to \mathbb C $ that sends $f\to f(\lambda)$ (which belongs to the characters of $A$ denoted bt $\Phi (A)$) then I proved that  the map$$\delta:\Omega\to \Phi (A)$$ $$\lambda \to \phi_{\lambda}$$ is injective, continuous and $\operatorname{Im}\delta$ is dense. I need help with the following:

1. Why the following sets are form a bases of $\Omega$ $$\{\lambda\in\Omega:|f_i(\lambda)-f_i(\lambda_{0})|<\epsilon,i=1,2,\dots,n\},$$ where $\lambda_{0}\in\Omega$,$f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n\in A$?
2. Why the sets in 1. gets mapped to an open set under $\delta$?
3. Why every complex bounded continuous function on $\Omega$ can be uniquely extended to $\Phi (A)$?

For part 3), I'm thinking to consider every such function as a functional  and use Hahn-Banach Theorem.
 I need your help please any ideas.

Comment: Short answer: in 1) use the definition of complete regularity. For 2): the map $\delta$ is always a homeomorphism onto its image (assuming that completely regular includes the Hausdorff condition), but the image is open if and only if $\Omega$ is locally compact. For 3) Uniqueness is clear by density of $\delta(\Omega)$ while existence ...well... a bounded function on $\Omega$ is a function on $\Phi(A)$ in a natural way, so you alrady have an extension.